# C array expression

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I'm trying to work a C practice problem:

What is the equivalent C array expression for the following pointer expression assuming `fubar` is defined as an array. It doesn't matter what type each array element is or how many elements are defined.

`*fubar` is equivalent to _____ (equivalent array expression using`[]` but no `*`)

My initial answer was `fubar[0]` but I really have no idea.

Comment: Yes `*fubar` is equivalent to `fubar[0]`

Comment: What made you think `fubar[0]` is not the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*fubar` is simply dereferencing `fubar`.

`fubar[0]` is equivalent to `*(fubar + 0)`. The reason for that is that `fubar` points to the beginning of the array, so if you jump `N` places after `fubar` you get to the `N-th` elemtent, i.e `fubar[k]`.

So yes, `*fubar` is equivalent to `fubar[0]`. Namely, `fubar = &(fubar[0])`

Comment: And also to `0[fubar]`, at least in C (but not in C++)

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure if that is legit ANSI C. It's a bad practice though.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. `*fubar` is equivalent to `fubar[0]`.

In general, `*(fubar + k)` is equivalent to `fubar[k]`.

Comment: And also to `k[fubar]`, at least in *C*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ah, yes, and that would fit the requirement in the question (using `[]` without `*`), too.

Answer (score 0):

Easily, you think like array's name means address.
So, `*(fubar + i)` is equivalent to `fubar[i]`.
So, it jumps i places after fubar you get to the i-th element.
To understand, see the blow example.
That is, `*(fubar+1)` is equivalent to `fubar[1]` and `*(fubar+2)` is equivalent to `fubar[2]`.